# redirect to page in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to redirect to same page in php using jquery as below:

```
echo "<script> 
    var url = window.location.href + '?a=eud';
    alert(url);
    $(location).attr('href',url); 
</script>";
```

When I execute above, I am getting alert message, but its not redirecting.

Sorry if its a dumb query, but i am new to php and having basic knowledge on jquery.

Comment: why not use php `Header('Location: yourphpfile.php');`

Comment: Add `//` before `alert(url);`. You can do it with simple JavaScript. Why do you use jquery?

Comment: `location.replace(url)`.

Comment: try this `window.location = '/path/yourfile.php';`

Comment: @Luthando Loot , it's sometimes bad. When you use this code after any text, it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you just have to get the PHP to `echo` the actual redirect command:

```
echo"
<script> 
    var url = window.location.href + '?a=eud';
    location.href = url; 
</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<script> 
    var url = window.location.href + '?a=eud';
    window.location = url;
</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<script> 
var url = window.location.href + '?a=eud';
window.location.replace(url);
</script>";
```